# How do I crawl through a site to search for a name and return URL when found confirming to robots.txt?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-crawler, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to put together a list of bios for names found in some websites.

I have names and corresponding websites :

```
name      website
-----------------
John Doe  abc.com
Steve J   apple.com
```

For instance, I want to search for John Doe @ http://abc.com

I want to fetch the urls in that site where John Doe was found :

ex :

```
http://abc.com/board/programmers.php
http://abc.com/team/list.php
http://abc.com/index/welcome.php
```

Of course I want to conform to robots.txt on each website. I am not data mining, I already know that a person 'X' is associated to a website 'Y' to list his bio. I am sure the website admin won't mind that!

I came across Scrapy but I don't know the exact URL where the name is found on a website. All I have is the root of the website and I want the crawler to crawl through each linked page.

While typing this I started wondering why not key in the search query and website in to Google and retireve the result all in an automated fashion - but Google doesn't let you do that in their ToS I assume.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22John+Doe%22+site:abc.com#q=%22John+Doe%22+site:abc.com&hl=de&prmd=ivnso&filter=0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=479bfbd97c80bbdb&biw=1399&bih=928 you could try [google's api](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Comment: Going through Google APIs that let me do this and retrieve results (title, url, website snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Using a search engine, either by scraping it or by using their API (if you can follow their Terms of Use), is definitely the way to go here.

See for example [how to do it with DuckDuckGo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38964931/939364).