# Duckduckgo API getting search results

Tags: api, duckduckgo-api

What I want to do is just submitting string queries (the equivalent of typing into the search bar by hand) and saving the URL of the first results (if there are any).

I have asked a similar question ( [Python search scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419626/python-search-scraping)) and the answer to it works well with google my problem is that I can't find Duckduckgo's search api address anywhere. Could you help me or suggest antoher way of doing this?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

tl;dr -- Screen scrape [https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q={search_terms}](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%7Bsearch_terms%7D)

As other answerers have mentioned, the URL for DuckDuckGo's **limited search** API is

```
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=x&format=json
```

`x` being the search terms you're looking for.

*However*, please note that this is *not a full search API*. As [DuckDuckGo's API page](https://api.duckduckgo.com/api) mentions,

> This API does not include all of our links, however. That is, it is not a full search results API or a way to get DuckDuckGo results into your applications beyond our instant answers. Because of the way [we generate our search results](https://duck.co/help/results/sources), we unfortunately do not have the rights to fully syndicate our results. For the same reason, we cannot allow framing our results without our branding. Please see [our partnerships page](https://duck.co/help/company/partnerships) for more info on guidelines and getting in touch with us.

> This is an Instant Answer API, and not a full results API. However, there are some Web links within it, e.g. official sites.

So for your stated purpose of

> just submitting string queries (the equivalent of typing into the search bar by hand) and saving the URL of the first results (if there are any).

api.duckduckgo.com will not get you what you want.

Your best bet is probably to just screen scrape the non-JS, web version of DuckDuckGo:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=x
```

looking for elements with a selector of something like `div.result` or `div.web-result`.

Comment: Thanks, so the last three lines are expounded in the linked question's answers?

Comment: @Nesa yep! Especially if you're interested in doing the screen-scraping in python.

Comment: Thanks for the experienced tip. Care to explain the benefits of using the JSON param?

Comment: The JSON param just tells the API to return you results in JSON format. I believe the only other option is `format=xml`. It may give you a JSON response without explicitly asking for it, but if so it's an undocumented feature and could change without notice.

Comment: I have something implemented for Image search here, This would be very similar to implement - https://github.com/deepanprabhu/duckduckgo-images-api

Comment: is there anyway to add time and location to query?

Comment: The api.duckduckgo.com domain doesn't seem to work for me anymore. Though just using the base `duckduckgo.com` domain with the `format=json` param does seem to work for me, ie. `http://duckduckgo.com/?q=x&format=json` for query `x`.

Answer (score 4):

just change  with whatever you want to search for.  This will output the results in JSON

```
https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=<your search string>&format=json&pretty=1&no_html=1&skip_disambig=1
```

I think this is what you are asking for

Comment: Its not working anymore or its not giving result for many queries I can confirm that.

Comment: @VivekSancheti can you tell me what you tried searching, everything I try is returning results in JSON format

Answer (score 3):

> www.api.duckduckgo.com/?q=`Search`&format=json&pretty=1

Example:
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json&pretty=1

The response is a JSON Object, you can find the address of the first link:

```
response.Results[0].FirstURL
```

You can find that out by putting the response into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Hope it helped :)